# PyQtWebkit and java script

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I have a  page with  js.
I need  get dom after js execute at  webpage. 
Js inserts text in the div with  name 'sdl'.
I need get  value  between  . Value can not be  parsed in js source, it is generated by Js.
How to do it?
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM is exposed (at least in pyqt >= 4.7.4)

```
document = webview.page().currentFrame().documentElement()
document.findAll("a") 
...
```

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebframe.html

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebelement.html

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use [Ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/), which is open source and available from github. It's a Python wrapper around the PyQt4+WebKit hack that works pretty well. You can just do

```
import ghost
g = ghost.Ghost()
g.open('http://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Now `g.content` refers to the document, post-rendering.

You can also evaluate JS in the doc with the `evaluate` method, and it'll return the JS values.

Ghost also exposes the PyQt objects pretty readily, so you can do stuff to a `Ghost` object that Ghost doesn't implement, and it'll pass through.

I can't remember exactly, but I think something like

```
g.main_frame.setContent('<b>Hello World</b>')
```

can be used to set the document, while

```
g.content = '<b>Hello World</b>'
```

throws one. It takes some taming, but it doesn't take long to get it working how you want it to.

The Ghost docs suck, but the source is a single file and pretty explanatory. I use Ghost and it's fine. Just don't create more than one `Ghost` object, else it tends to crash everything.